# angular splice overwriting element on move fromIndex, toIndex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, splice

I have an array exposed to `$scope` called exercises containing an array of exercises which are objects like this:

```
[
   {
     "exerciseName": "Half Lunge ",
     "exerciseDescription": "Stand with one foot forward taking most of your weight.",
     "images": [71,73]
   }
]
```

I aim to move an exercise from one position to another using the following:

```
$scope.moveItem = function(exercise, fromIndex, toIndex) {
 $scope.exercises.splice(fromIndex, 1);
 $scope.exercises.splice(toIndex, 0, exercise);
};
```

However this is overwriting the exercise in the `toIndex` with the data from the `fromIndex`

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/PqZybN/?editors=101)

Answer (score 1):

you are passing one extra perameter in your function.
just remove that exercises perameter from your element.

```
<ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveItem(exercise, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>
```

edited [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqxERB)

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the element at position fromIndex.
You are then adding the element exercise at index toIndex.

It all depends on what indices you provide. If fromIndex is the index of your exercise object and toIndex is where you want it moved, then it should work.

It would be more clear if you just had a to and from index and not an exercise object as function parameters. Then you cold do:

```
$scope.moveItem = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
    var exercise = $scope.exercises[fromIndex];
    $scope.exercises.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    $scope.exercises.splice(toIndex, 0, exercise);
};
```

Comment: It is an object from ng-repeat that has `track by index` on it ?

Comment: You don't need track by index if you don't have duplicate objects in your array.

I can't answer your question any better without seeing the code from where moveItem() is called.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if (columns[i].name === movedColumnName) {
            movedColumnIndex = i;
        }
        if (columns[i].name === insertColumnName) {
            insertColumnIndex = i;
        }
    }

        var movedColumn = columns.splice(movedColumnIndex, 1)[0];
        columns.splice(insertColumnIndex, 0,movedColumn);

    };
```